# How do I insert data into an array in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql

The codes are for executing same query for different servers. I use `foreach` loop to connect different servers, and use `updateDB` function to perform the query. 
 I need to record failed connections into an array.

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {

  $servername =  $value;

  $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $database);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      echo $servername."Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error."<br>";
      $errorMessage = array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error);
  }
  else {
    echo $servername." ".$database." Connected Succesfully <br>";
    updateDB($data, $servername, $conn);
  }
  $conn-> close();
}
```

However, the array only saves the last record of failed connections.
The correct `echo` output are as followed:

```
192.168.0.2 Connection failed: No route to host
192.168.0.3 Connection failed: No route to host
192.168.0.25 Connection failed: No route to host
192.168.0.47 Connection failed: No route to host
```

But, when I `print_r` my array `$errorMessage`, it only shows:

```
Array ( [0] => 192.168.0.47 [1] => No route to host )
```

And the first 3 records are not inside the array.

I know something is wrong with

> $errorMessage = array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error);

But I've searched over and can't find a solution. Please help. TQ

Comment: declare an array before the `foreach` loop and append `$errorMessage` to it

Comment: Find a solution for __what__?

Comment: @u_mulder to have all the records saved in the array

Comment: `$errorMessage[] = array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error);` This may be resolve your issue.

Comment: What records? What array?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this method doesn't work

Comment: @Shivrudra thx very much..it works !!

Comment: what was the downvote for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add new array in existing array element rather than override the previous array.

```
$errorMessage[] = array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add to the array not write new one on every loop.

```
$errorMessages = array();
foreach ($lines as $value) {

    $servername = $value;

    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      echo $servername."Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error;
      $errorMessages[] = array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo $servername." ".$database." Connected Succesfully";
        updateDB($data, $servername, $conn);
    }
    $conn-> close();
}
```

`$errorMessages`will contain the error messages you want.

Answer (score 0):

Personally always use Array Push:

```
array_push($errorMessages, array("Servername" => $servername , "Error" => $conn->connect_error));
```

This adds an element to the end of your array. For more info see [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)